# tsc tsconfig.json settings to compile to JS classes compatible with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, requirejs, tsc

I have a Typescript interface, an abstract class (which implements the interface), and a class that extends the abstract class.  This Typescript library I'm building uses jQuery quite a bit and takes `$` as an argument in it's constructor.

I'd like to use `tsc` to compile this into Javascript classes that will be included using reactjs, targeting Webkit / Safari 537.

I'm using `requirejs` to add jQuery and the generated library as follows:

```
define(["jquery","vham"],function ($,VHAM) {
    alert('$: ' + $);        // This exists
    alert('VHAM: ' + VHAM);  // This crashes
 ...
```

js/app/main.js

All of my library javascript code is output to `js/lib/vham.js`; `vham.js` is the output of the `tsc` compiler.  What settings are appropriate in `tsconfig.json` for compiling my classes for use as a dependency included using requirejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RequireJS uses Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD). You would need to tell tsc to generate modules in AMD format. Specifically you will need to set the `--module` flag to "AMD".

See the Typescript Compiler Options for more details:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html